# Javascript auto generate unique id for textbox

Tags: javascript

In javascript I got problem in create unique auto generate id in textbox. the textbox must be readonly. please help. The Id should be like this PT1

```
<tr>
    <td>Patient AdmissionID:</td>
    <td><input type="text" readonl  placeholder="Patient ID"/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Don't you want to consider entries in the DB ?

Comment: Yeah i wanna entries in DB

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-container">
  <input type="text" id="PT1">
</div>

<button id="addInput">Add Input</button>$('#addInput').on('click',function(){
    var inputCount = $(".input-container").find($("input"));
        var uniqueInput = "PT"+inputCount.length + 1;
    $(".input-container").append("<input type='text' id='" +uniqueInput+ "'>");
})
```

Working Fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/657/